# drivine how to set neo4j connection info without environment variables

Tags: node.js, typescript, neo4j, drivine

In the Drivine neo4j driver, how do I set the application to connect to a specified database in code without setting the environment variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To register a new connection dynamically:**

Ensure that the following code has been called first:

```
DatabaseRegistry.getInstance().builder()
        .withType(DatabaseType.NEO4J)
        .host(host)
        .userName(userName)
        .password(password)
        .databaseName(dbName) // On Neo4j version 4 we can have multiple DBs
        .port(nonStandardPortIfNeeded)
        .register('MY_UNIQUE_NAME');
```

**Note:** Rather than using the `DatabaseRegistry` as a singleton, you can of course also `@Inject()` it.

The code above could go in the body of the constructor below, or anywhere, as long as it is called before the persistence manager is obtained from the factory.

**Obtain Persistence Manager From Factory:**

Once a database has been registered, you can obtain a persistence manager for that db, like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class PersonRepository {

    readonly persistenceManager: PersistenceManager;

    constructor(@Inject() readonly factory: PersistenceManagerFactory) {
    }

    async someOperation(): Promise<void> {
        const persistenceManager = this.factory.get('MY_UNIQUE_NAME')
        //Now use persistence manager 
    }

}
```

**Details:**

- In the first case we use the `DatabaseRegistry`'s builder to build or resolve a named `ConnectionProvider` with the specified properties.
- In the second case we use the `PersistenceManagerFactory` to obtain a `PersistenceManager` for the named connection details. The connection provider takes care of returning a connection (possibly pooled depending on platform) for that database in the most expedient manner.

And that's it. By the way, [Drivine](https://drivine.org) works for other graph databases as well.

Comment: To clarify .`databaseName(dbName)` is the url of the database, correct?

Comment: https://adamcowley.co.uk/neo4j/multi-tenancy-neo4j-4.0/.   <-- Neo4j v4 supports multiple databases in once server. If you have created additional databases, as per Adam's guide, then we can use them in Drivine by specifying the name. With no name, it will use the default v1,2 and 3.x compatible DB.

Comment: So if you have created a database called 'customers' you put the string 'customers'. Not the URL, just the string name.

Comment: So wait, where does the database address/url go then?

Comment: OK, looked at the database api docs. The example is missing .host

https://drivine.org/api/classes/_src_connection_connectionproviderbuilder_.connectionproviderbuilder.html

Comment: Oops, sorry @AoiGhost!!. Have added it now.